# Google maps, get destination coo

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Just starting use google maps api and got stuck how I can get position of origin and destination ?

I want use them in admin panel to change position and save.

I found how to make with marker but need same with TravelMode.

**Marker script:**

```
    ...
    var point = marker.getPosition();
    map.panTo(point);

    // Update text fields with lat and lng
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = point.lat();
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = point.lng();
```

**Current my script:**

```
<script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {

 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          //suppressMarkers: true,
          //suppressInfoWindows: true,
          draggable: true,
          polylineOptions: {
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                    strokeWeight: 5
                },
     });


var request = {
  origin:     new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $start_ps["lat"].', '.$start_ps["lon"]; ?>),
  <?php foreach ($waypoints as $wp) {
        $loc = ToLL( $wp["A"], $wp["B"], '35');
        echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$loc["lat"].', '.$loc["lon"].'),'; echo "\n";
} ?>

  destination:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $end_ps["lat"].', '.$end_ps["lon"]; ?>),      
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};



directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
}
});



var vilnius = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $start_ps["lat"].', '.$start_ps["lon"]; ?>);

var mapOptions = {
  zoom:7,
  center: vilnius
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: use `request.origin.lat()` , `request.origin.lng()`  `request.destination.lat()` and so on. For the waypoints you must iterate over the waypoints(it's an array) and e.g. create the form-fields dynamically(when the number of waypoints isn't static)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, then directions changed you can use:

**Start:**

directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat()
directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng()

**End:**

directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lat()
directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lng()

**Test alert: show changed start location**

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function (event) {

       alert("lat: " + directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat() + " \n lng: " + directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng());

});
```